# Key Error after droping null values in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

I have a simple dataframe as :

```
0   1   2   3
1   NaN like    dislike
2   Cow dog snail
```

After dropping the nan value the dataframe is :

```
0   1   2   3
2   Cow dog snail
```

Now when I try the following code to print the values it gives key error :

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(data.loc[i,:])
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following line after dropping nan values:

```
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're dropping a value with an specific index in which after dropping NA values will not exist anymore. In your specific case, the index `1` will be dropped and you won't be able to iterate your dataframe via `len`. I highly recommend you to use `iterrows` instead as it's better form. Example:

```
for index, value in mydataframe.iterrows():
    print(index, " ",  value)
    # 2 
    # 1    Cow
    # 2    dog
    # 3    snail
```

The value is of class `'pandas.core.series.Series'` which in your case functions a lot like a dictionary. Pay attention to the column names which are exactly the ones in your example.